# Can’t move a method that uses super

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I'm reading [this book](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_classes.html#details-of-subclassing). Check section "15.6.4.2 Pitfall: **A method that uses super can’t be moved**"

It states the following

> You can’t move a method that uses super: Such a method has the
>   internal slot [[HomeObject]] that ties it to the object it was created
>   in. If you move it via an assignment, it will continue to refer to the
>   superproperties of the original object.

So, I tried to call it with a different object, also assign instance method to a different object but it seems not to work. It refers to new object's properties. Probably, I didn't get correctly what the author means. So, could anyone, please, provide an example?

Hers is a [small demo](https://jsfiddle.net/xfbosev6/1/) and the code below

```
class A {
  get a() {
    return 1;
  }

  sayHi() {
    console.log(this.a)
  }
}

class B extends A {
  sayHi() {
    super.sayHi();
  };
}
var obj = {
  a: 4
};
let b = new B();
b.sayHi();
// logs 1

b.sayHi.call(obj);
// logs 4

obj.sayHi = b.sayHi;
obj.sayHi();
// logs 4
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code is OK, because `this` works when you move a method, but `super` doesn’t (and your code only really tests `this`). The following code tests `super`:

```
class Bird {
  getName() {
    return 'Bird';
  }
}
class Mammal {
  getName() {
    return 'Mammal';
  }
}
class Human extends Mammal {
  getName() {
    return super.getName();
  }
}
class Duck extends Bird {
}
// Moving method .getName() from Human.prototype to Duck.prototype
Duck.prototype.getName = Human.prototype.getName;

console.log(new Duck().getName()); // 'Mammal' (not 'Bird')
```

To understand the result, you need to understand how `super` works – it uses the internal property `[[HomeObject]]` that is stored in the method itself, it does not rely on `this`. That is, `Human.prototype.getName()` internally works as follows:

```
Human.prototype.getName = Object.assign(
  function me() {
    return me.__HomeObject__.__proto__.getName();
  },
  { __HomeObject__: Human.prototype }
);
```

More details are explained in the [book](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_classes.html#superproperties):

Comment: OP is reading exactly that book, and doesn't understand what "moving a method" means or why a different result might be expected

Answer (score 1):

OP is saying that `super.sayHi()` will always call `A.prototype.sayHi`, regardless on what object you call the method. One might have expected

```
const sayHi = new B().sayHi; // or B.prototype.sayHi

const prototype = {
  sayHi() {
    console.log("not the a property");
  }
};
const myObject = Object.assign(Object.create(prototype), {
  a: "the a property"
});
myObject.sayHi = sayHi;
myObject.sayHi();
// or just sayHi.call(myObject);
```

to log not the `a` property - by calling `prototype.sayHi` through the prototype chain of `myObject`. But that is not what happens, it logs the `a` property as normal.

Comment: so why does it log `a` property as normal? has it been fixed in the newer versions of EcmaScript?

Comment: @MaxWizardK No, `super` always works like this since its incarnation in ES6?

Comment: okay, so what did the author mean in the book by "If you move it via an assignment, it will continue to refer to the superproperties of the original object." ?

Comment: @MaxWizardK Just what I had done via `call` - see the edit